# Apache pulsar get timeout in unpredictable way

Tags: apache-pulsar

I installed Apache pulsar standalone. Pulsar get timeout sometimes. It's not related to high throuput neither to a particular topic (following log). Pulsar-admin brokers healthcheck returns OK or timeout also. How to investigate on it ?

```
10:46:46.365 [pulsar-ordered-OrderedExecutor-7-0] WARN  org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.BrokerService - Got exception when reading persistence policy for persistent://nnx/agent_ns/action_up-53da8177-b4b9-4b92-8f75-efe94dc2309d: null
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.pulsar.zookeeper.ZooKeeperDataCache.get(ZooKeeperDataCache.java:97) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-zookeeper-utils-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.BrokerService.lambda$getManagedLedgerConfig$32(BrokerService.java:922) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-broker-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.bookkeeper.mledger.util.SafeRun$2.safeRun(SafeRun.java:49) [org.apache.pulsar-managed-ledger-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.bookkeeper.common.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:36) [org.apache.bookkeeper-bookkeeper-common-4.10.0.jar:4.10.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_232]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [io.netty-netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
```

Comment: Problem was 8 cores was not sufficient for our pulsar usage (20 topics real time). After tuning Pulsar and above all increasing number of core, timeout has disapeared.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you were able to resolve the issue my adding more cores. The issue was a connection timeout while trying to access some topic metadata that is stored inside of ZookKeeper as indicated by the following line in the stack trace:

at org.apache.pulsar.zookeeper.ZooKeeperDataCache.get(ZooKeeperDataCache.java:97) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-zookeeper-utils-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]

Increasing the cores must of freed up enough threads to allow the ZK node to respond to this request.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the connection to the server looks like connection issue if you are using any TLScertificate file path check if you have the right certificate.
The Problem is we don't have lot of solutions in internet for apache pulsar but if you are following the apache pulsar doc might help and also we have apache pulsar git hub and sample projects.